# How Can I Generate Local Notifications During Background Fetch for iOS Using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3

How can I make an app to fetch small json data from a web server once a day at 8 AM, and generate a local notification only If the data matches certain condition? How can I combine both local notification and background fetch? Is this possible? I'd like to avoid remote (push) notification. Thanks!

Comment: You can just schedule a local notification from the background fetch, but there is no way to specify that your background fetch occurs at a specific time.

Comment: Thanks! Wow, no scheduler for a specific task on iOS? Only you can schedule a local notification? Surprising.